# Error messages in the XML layout in Android 2020-3-1, Touch size too small

Tags: android

In Android version 2020.3.1 I get many errors in the xml layout. E.g. in EditTexts 'Touch size too small' although the height of the field is set to WrapContent and TextSize is 14 dp.
The message says: 'This item's height is 46dp *). Consider making the height of this touch target 48dp or larger.'

Do I now have to enter 'Ignore ...' for each field or can I ignore the messages?

*) I use the implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.6' to automatically adjust the text height to the screen resolution and specify the text height e.g. in '@dimen/_14sdp'. Could this be the reason?

Comment: try this answer here, it solved my problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76162136/android-studio-xml-file-with-edittext-gives-error-titletxt-edittext-touch-t