# android studio xml file with edittext gives error : titletxt <EditText>: Touch target size too small how to fix

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-xml

i have simple android application containing xml file with simple edittext and button and recycler view
below my xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/titletxt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"

            android:hint="Enter Information"

            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"

            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:text="Submit"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recycler"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#E8DDDD"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

when i build the app or run it it gives the error below

> titletxt : Touch target size too small

Comment: It is a warning more than an error. Your project should compile but you should consider that some constraints cause that the edittext whose id  is *titletxt* get pressed its height. Try to adjust the margins or just give it a fixed height of 48dp at least.

Comment: I ran this xml. It didn't crash. You should add Logcat.

Answer (score 9):

Edit Text's height is 45dp. Minimum required height of this touch target is 48dp or larger.

You can find more information at https://support.google.com/accessibility/android/answer/7101858

Just add `android:minHeight="48dp"` to the editText.